# Can you count clicks on a certain frame in an animation in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to build a very simple whack a mole-esque game in javascript. Right now I know how to do everything else except the scoring. My current animation code is as follows

```
<script language="JavaScript"
type="text/javascript">
    var urls;

function animate(pos) {
  pos %= urls.length;
  document.images["animation"].src=urls[pos];
  window.setTimeout("animate(" + (pos + 1) + ");",  
  500);

}

window.onload = function() {
  urls = new Array(
    "Frame1.jpg","Frame2.jpg" 

);
  animate(0);
}
</script>
```

So far it all works, the first frame is the hole and the second is the groundhog/mole out of the hole. I need to count the clicks on the second frame but I can't figure out how to incorporate a counter. Help? (Sorry if the code doesn't show up correctly, first time using this site)

Comment: Don't pass a string to `setTimeout`/`setInterval`. It's `eval` in disguise. Instead, pass a `function`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example that counts clicks on the flashing animation: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/TQqJ8/

JS:

```
function animate(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation = document.getElementById('animation');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation.src = urls[pos];
    animation.onclick = function() {
        counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate(++pos);
    }, 500);
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Here is a fiddle that only detects click on one of the images: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/TQqJ8/8/

Comment: That works great, thanks, one issue though, how would I go about making it only count the clicks when the second frame is visible? Ex:Only clicks on the second flash in that example.

Comment: @Steven: this one only detects the click on the pink image: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/TQqJ8/8/