# Only starting a function on button click?(javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

How would I make a start button for a function? I have 9 different functions for different animations on my page. I need to figure out how execute the animations only when a button is clicked(a start button) The reason why I want to do this is because I'm making a simple game, but I'd like the end user to be able to interact with the elements of the game before they start(I already have this done with jQuery, but at the moment I can only move the elements while the game is running which isn't what I want to do.) A quick example of the animate function is

```
function animate0(pos) {
    pos %= urls.length;
    var animation0 = document.getElementById('animation0');
    var counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    animation0.src = urls[pos];
    if (pos == 1) {
        animation0.onclick = function() {
            counter.innerHTML = parseInt(counter.innerHTML) + 1;
        }
    }
    else {
        animation0.onclick = function() {
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        animate0(++pos);
    }, (Math.random()*500) + 1000);
}
```

Then to execute the animation I use this

```
window.onload = function() { //Frames go below, seperated by commas format= , "URL");
    urls = new Array("http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif", "http://i56.tinypic.com/2i3tyw.gif");
    animate0(0);
```

To display the animation on the page,

```
<img id='animation0' src ='http://i51.tinypic.com/sxheeo.gif'/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539706/can-you-count-clicks-on-a-certain-frame-in-an-animation-in-javascript  This is related to this question....

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('start').onclick = function(){
    animate0(0);
}
```

This is assuming you have an element with `id='start'`

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/TQqJ8/13/

Comment: Thanks Neal, I appreciate all your help, I've gone through 3 different variations of this so far. :P Turns out your animation code was the best for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think I may be misunderstanding your question, but if for instance you had this button (or indeed just about any other element):

```
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="Click Me">
```

Then you can hook up a handler for its `click` event in any of several ways.

1. The simplest, but least powerful, is DOM0-style:

   ```
   document.getElementById("theButton").onclick = function() {
       animate0(0);
       return false;
   };
   ```

   The problem with DOM0 handlers is that there can only be *one* handler/event type on each element.
2. DOM2-style, which on standards-based browsers looks like this:

   ```
   document.getElementById("theButton").addEventListener('click', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       animate0(0);
   }, false);
   ```

   ...and on older IE looks like this:

   ```
   document.getElementById("theButton").attachEvent('onclick', function() {
       animate0(0);
       return false;
   });
   ```

Note the differences, the event name is "click" in the DOM2 standard, "onclick" for Microsoft, and the `event` object is passed in the first argument in the DOM2 standard, but it's a global variable (I didn't use) on Microsoft's older browsers. (Not dissing Microsoft, in the IE5 - IE6 timeframe, they did a *lot* to innovate web browsers, including ajax, `innerHTML`, and in fact multiple handlers per event per element via `attachEvent`, which predates the DOM2 standard. It's just *after* IE6 that they let the ball drop for...well...more than a decade.)

In all of those cases, I've called `animate0` directly, since it does its first loop and then schedules the next bit itself. You could, of course, use `setTimeout` to schedule even the first bit to be asynchronous (probably just use a delay of `0`, which will be 5-10 ms on most browsers). It depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I'm not saying I (necessarily) recommend it, but surely the "simplest" is to put the `onclick=...` inline in the HTML?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Nah, then you have all these global functions running around, which can get  complicated, and you have to remember to include the word "return" so you can prevent the default action. ;-) (Okay, that's a bit tongue-in-cheek. Mostly I didn't list that because it's not best practice, and the OP seemed happy with assigning handlers unobtrusively.)

Comment: Ahah, I was just looking for something that works, of course there are probably cleaner ways of going about my entire project, but since I'm just beginning I just want to learn the syntax and such. I'll worry about the best/cleanest way of doing stuff later.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder - speaking of preventing the default action, that's kind of overkill when the control in question is just an `<input type="button">` - there's not really a default to prevent. I remember thinking that when I first read your answer and saw you'd included those `return false;` and `preventDefault()` statements in your functions. I'm trying to decide if it's a good habit to get into to just always do it to be sure not to forget in the cases where it is necessary.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Agreed, for elements with no default action, going to lengths to prevent is is unnecessary. I don't do it in my own code, but I do it in code samples people may be applying to things with default actions, like links. :-) I should probably flag that up when I do it.